# Problem cause when install/try ubuntu from USB; got squashfs errors on Dell Inspiron 11

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, squashfs

It looks like Squashfs errors were prevalent in the past but I haven't seen much recently. I'm using a Dell Inspiron 11 3000 with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. I turned off fastboot, secure boot, still on UEFI boot mode so I should be good to go for a dual boot/usb live setup. I checked the Ubuntu disk and tried 2 different ISOs to no avail.

I used `Unetbootin` to make a bootable USB, fyi. I did a memory check, no errors. I tried 2 different thumb drives, no dice. According to the older problems associated with SquashFS errors, I've checked everything and I can't find a reason why there's a problem. So when I reboot and `try Ubuntu`, I see the Ubuntu loading splash screen, then it goes to lots of lines of the squash errors so then I have to hard restart. Any help or suggestions besides wiping the whole thing and running only Ubuntu in Legacy BIOS would be great.